# Secure, simple php faq creating/editing script to base further development off of?

Tags: php, authentication, scripting, administrative

I'm looking to build a simple site centered around a simple faq system in php.  The faq concept is simple, but I want to have an administrative-access backend for editing and creating the entries, and securing a login seems more complex and time-consuming, so I'm looking for suggestions for code to start me off.

Does anyone know of any open source php scripts or snippets that would work as base code for administrative login to some php scripts that could be used as a simple faq system?  Or base code for both, the faq php code + web administrative access code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at a script repository like [Hot Scripts](http://www.hotscripts.com/search/php/faq).